# mysql > java.sql.SQLException: Plugin '*765C23FCC8127A2234DBCFB6E5207D82ED86264E' is not loaded

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

(using: Ubuntu 14.04, Tomcat 7.0.59, Java 8 (Oracle), mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar, MySQL 5.7.7, Eclipse 4.4.1)

since yesterday I get this strange exception telling me that "a plugin is not loaded" on server startup. I can't find anything about it. Results are that no datasource / connection pool is being created - connections to the database are not possible.

Because there are several warnings & severe messages in the log with different reasons ("Unable to create initial connections of pool.", "Unexpected exception resolving reference", "Failed to register in JMX") I decided to just paste the whole monster here (a little stripped, because this here is ltd. to 30000 chars):

```
Jun 06, 2015 10:32:00 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:mymyAppRest' did not find a matching property.
Jun 06, 2015 10:32:01 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 06, 2015 10:32:01 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Jun 06, 2015 10:32:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMATION: Initialization processed in 925 ms
Jun 06, 2015 10:32:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting service Catalina
Jun 06, 2015 10:32:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.59
Jun 06, 2015 10:32:05 AM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
SEVERE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: Plugin '*765C23FCC8127A2234DBCFB6E5207D82ED86264E' is not loaded
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
  ...
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2239)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2270)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2069)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:486)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:554)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:141)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:842)
  ...
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5412)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jun 06, 2015 10:32:05 AM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException: Plugin '*765C23FCC8127A2234DBCFB6E5207D82ED86264E' is not loaded
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
  ...
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2239)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2270)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2069)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:486)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:554)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:141)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:842)
  ...
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5412)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jun 06, 2015 10:32:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Plugin '*765C23FCC8127A2234DBCFB6E5207D82ED86264E' is not loaded
2015-06-06 10:32:05 INFO  QuartzInitializerListener:147 - Quartz Initializer Servlet loaded, initializing Scheduler...
Jun 06, 2015 10:32:05 AM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
SEVERE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: Plugin '*765C23FCC8127A2234DBCFB6E5207D82ED86264E' is not loaded
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
  ...
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2239)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2270)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2069)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:486)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:554)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:141)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:842)
  ...
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:156)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.quartz.utils.JNDIConnectionProvider.init(JNDIConnectionProvider.java:124)
    at org.quartz.utils.JNDIConnectionProvider.<init>(JNDIConnectionProvider.java:102)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:993)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1519)
    at org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener.contextInitialized(QuartzInitializerListener.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jun 06, 2015 10:32:05 AM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException: Plugin '*765C23FCC8127A2234DBCFB6E5207D82ED86264E' is not loaded
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
  ...

2015-06-06 10:32:05 ERROR JNDIConnectionProvider:126 - Error looking up datasource: Plugin '*765C23FCC8127A2234DBCFB6E5207D82ED86264E' is not loaded
javax.naming.NamingException: Plugin '*765C23FCC8127A2234DBCFB6E5207D82ED86264E' is not loaded
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:859)
  ...
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:156)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.quartz.utils.JNDIConnectionProvider.init(JNDIConnectionProvider.java:124)
    at org.quartz.utils.JNDIConnectionProvider.<init>(JNDIConnectionProvider.java:102)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:993)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1519)
    at org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener.contextInitialized(QuartzInitializerListener.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-06-06 10:32:05 INFO  StdSchedulerFactory:1184 - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
2015-06-06 10:32:05 INFO  SchedulerSignalerImpl:61 - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2015-06-06 10:32:05 INFO  QuartzScheduler:240 - Quartz Scheduler v.2.2.1 created.
2015-06-06 10:32:05 INFO  JobStoreTX:670 - Using thread monitor-based data access locking (synchronization).
2015-06-06 10:32:05 INFO  JobStoreTX:59 - JobStoreTX initialized.
2015-06-06 10:32:05 INFO  QuartzScheduler:305 - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.1) 'mymyScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 3 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX' - which supports persistence. and is not clustered.

2015-06-06 10:32:05 INFO  StdSchedulerFactory:1339 - Quartz scheduler 'mymyScheduler' initialized from the specified file : 'quartz.properties' from the class resource path.
2015-06-06 10:32:05 INFO  StdSchedulerFactory:1343 - Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.1
2015-06-06 10:32:05 DEBUG SimpleSemaphore:81 - Lock 'TRIGGER_ACCESS' is desired by: localhost-startStop-1
2015-06-06 10:32:05 DEBUG SimpleSemaphore:88 - Lock 'TRIGGER_ACCESS' is being obtained: localhost-startStop-1
2015-06-06 10:32:05 DEBUG SimpleSemaphore:105 - Lock 'TRIGGER_ACCESS' given to: localhost-startStop-1
Jun 06, 2015 10:32:05 AM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
SEVERE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: Plugin '*765C23FCC8127A2234DBCFB6E5207D82ED86264E' is not loaded
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2239)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2270)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2069)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:486)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:554)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:141)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:842)
  ...
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:156)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.quartz.utils.JNDIConnectionProvider.getConnection(JNDIConnectionProvider.java:144)
    at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.getConnection(DBConnectionManager.java:108)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:775)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreTX.java:71)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3784)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:834)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:690)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:567)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.start(StdScheduler.java:142)
    at org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener.contextInitialized(QuartzInitializerListener.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jun 06, 2015 10:32:05 AM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException: Plugin '*765C23FCC8127A2234DBCFB6E5207D82ED86264E' is not loaded
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
  ...

2015-06-06 10:32:05 DEBUG SimpleSemaphore:132 - Lock 'TRIGGER_ACCESS' retuned by: localhost-startStop-1
org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'mymy_pool': java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:comp/env/jdbc/mymy_pool' javax.naming.NamingException: Plugin '*765C23FCC8127A2234DBCFB6E5207D82ED86264E' is not loaded [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:comp/env/jdbc/mymy_pool' javax.naming.NamingException: Plugin '*765C23FCC8127A2234DBCFB6E5207D82ED86264E' is not loaded]]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:692)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:567)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.start(StdScheduler.java:142)
    at org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener.contextInitialized(QuartzInitializerListener.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)2015-06-06 10:32:05 ERROR QuartzInitializerListener:232 - Quartz Scheduler failed to initialize: org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'mymy_pool': java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:comp/env/jdbc/mymy_pool' javax.naming.NamingException: Plugin '*765C23FCC8127A2234DBCFB6E5207D82ED86264E' is not loaded [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:comp/env/jdbc/mymy_pool' javax.naming.NamingException: Plugin '*765C23FCC8127A2234DBCFB6E5207D82ED86264E' is not loaded]]

  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'mymy_pool': java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:comp/env/jdbc/mymy_pool' javax.naming.NamingException: Plugin '*765C23FCC8127A2234DBCFB6E5207D82ED86264E' is not loaded [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:comp/env/jdbc/mymy_pool' javax.naming.NamingException: Plugin '*765C23FCC8127A2234DBCFB6E5207D82ED86264E' is not loaded]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:778)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreTX.java:71)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3784)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:834)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:690)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:comp/env/jdbc/mymy_pool' javax.naming.NamingException: Plugin '*765C23FCC8127A2234DBCFB6E5207D82ED86264E' is not loaded
    at org.quartz.utils.JNDIConnectionProvider.getConnection(JNDIConnectionProvider.java:163)
    at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.getConnection(DBConnectionManager.java:108)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:775)
    ... 16 more
```

**update**: after searching the logs I also found this:

```
2015-06-06T10:29:28.145846Z 0 [Warning] The plugin '*765C23FCC8127A2234DBCFB6E5207D82ED86264E' used to authenticate user 'mymy-services'@'localhost' is not loaded. Nobody can currently login using this account.
```

(this *765C...64E seems to be the string representation of a C pointer)

Comment: Hi, could you show me your mysql config file? and also, is it possible to check the content of plugins table?

Comment: do you still want to see that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, found it ... really strange.

The reason was that (why ever) in the table mysql.users the authentication string "*765c...64E" was in the field "plugin" and not in the field "authentication_string" for the user "mymy-services".

The field "authentication_string" was null. So I recreated the user and everything was fine again.

How this happend ... no-one knows. Maybe it had to do with and upgrade from 5.6 to 5.7.7. But I doubt that, because I think it worked after the update ...

Comment: I have the same problem. But create new user did not help. Any tips please?